# Changing <tr> class every in a foreach loop every 2 times

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to change the tr class every 2 times in my loop, but I'm not too sure about how I can count the two times. So far I have:

```
foreach(array_chunk($users, 2, true) as $array){

}
```

I split the `$users` array chunks of two, but where can I go on from here?

What I am trying to output:

```
<tr class="m0">
    <td><a href="id.php?id=1">Bob</a></td>
    <td><a href="profile.php?id=2">Bob's Cousin</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="m1">
    <td><a href="profile.php?id=3">Bob's Mom</a></td>
    <td><a href="profile.php?id=4">Bob's Dad</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does your `$users` array contain?

Comment: @AmalMurali Just the usernames.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `print_r($users)`.

Comment: have you tried to insert a condition inside the loop with a modulo?

Comment: Just to add to @kevinabelita's comment, there's no need to chunk your users' array if you go this _(commonly used)_ route.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need alternate names? if it's just for styling then you could just use css "nth-child"

Example:

CSS

```
  table#results tr:nth-child(even)
    {
    background-color: red;
    }
        table#results tr:nth-child(odd)
    {
    background-color: blue;
    }
```

HTML

```
<table id="results">
<tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eh7qm/